# Sort by using drop down variable from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm new to PHP, and I have a simple table from a MySQL database. What I want to do is sort the table using the selected value from the drop down box, with the data from that row in the database.

[image]

Here is my code (selected is what I need for the drop down box):

```
$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];

if ($orderby == 'selected') { 
    $orderby_query = "WHERE timeStamp LIKE 'selected'";}
else { 
    $orderby_query = "";
}

$con = mysql_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
$db = mysql_select_db("xxxx",$con);
$get = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(timeStamp) FROM deliverys ORDER BY timeStamp DESC");
$timeStamp = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
    $timeStamp .= '<option value   ="'.$row['timeStamp'].'">'.$row['timeStamp'].'</option>';
}

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr style="font-weight:bold;" valign="top" height="30px" bgcolor="#999999">
<td><form name="sorter0" action="index.php" method="get">
<label title="date">Date</label><br />
<select name="orderby" OnChange="document.sorter0.submit();"><br /><br />
<option>Sort by Date</option>
<option value=''>--?--</option><?php echo $timeStamp; ?></option>
</select>
</form></td>
```

I don't know if I'm adding the data to the drop down box correctly because, if I click, the site reloads and I can see it say:

`/index.php?orderby=05-09-2015`

If I use a "fixed" value like `yes` or `no` it works.

Comment: what you want actually.and what is expected? show through some screenshot. what problem you are facing?

Comment: tel me meaning of following lines ...  `$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
if ($orderby == 'selected')
    $orderby_query = "WHERE timeStamp LIKE 'selected'";}`

Comment: selected is, just a made up word , I need a value from the drop down box, in a fixed dropdown it is YES and then it sorts by a given row where it says yes.

Comment: @DoubleH  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deliverys $orderby_query");